# delay_fnn in Julia causes StackOverflow error

Tags: julia

I have a univariate timeseries and I am trying to do State Space Reconstruction with it using Delayed Coordninate embedding. While attempting to calculate the optimal delay and embedding dimension I am able to get an optimal delay value of `2` however when I try to estimate the embedding dimension using `delay_fnn()` I get a StackOverflow error.

Here's the code:

````
using XLSX
using DataFrames
using DynamicalSystems
using Plots

f = XLSX.readtable("data.xlsx","TIME SIGNAL 400 RPM") 
f = DataFrame(f) # 48000x2 DataFrame
rec = f[1:10000,2] # Using only the first 10000 points for state space reconstruction
τ = estimate_delay(rec,"mi_min") # returns 2

#plot(selfmutualinfo(rec,1:10)) # plot verifies value returned by estimate_delay

plot(delay_fnn(rec,τ,1:10)) # Gives StackOverflow error```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `rec = f[1:10000,2]` returns a `Vector{Any}`. This takes up way more memory than necessary. This was easily fixed by typecasting the variable to `Vector{Float64}`.